# SELECT with count(*) clause

Tags: sql, oracle

my database tables:

```
//TABLE1
tname       
-----------
brazil     
spain       
england
```

in my table 2:

```
//Table2
title      date
-------------------------
 test1      15-jun-2012
 test2      16-jun-2012
 test3      14-AUG-2011
```

in my table 3 :

```
//Table3
Tname      title
------------------
 brazil     test1
 brazil     test2
 spain      test3
```

my question is to find the tname that occur since 2012 , which mean 1st January 2012

so my query is

```
 select tname,
        NVL(count(*),0) as total 
   from table1 t1 
  inner join table3 t3 
     on t1.tname = t3.tname 
  inner join table2 t2 
     on t3.title = t2.title
  where (TO_CHAR(date,'yyyy-mm-dd') > '2012-01-01');
```

expected output:

```
//result
tname        total
-------------------
 brazil        2
 spain         0
 england       0
```

Comment: What data type is date?  a string compairison isn't really what your after is it?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `group by` clause:

```
 select tname, NVL(count(*),0) as total
 from table1 t1 inner join
      table3 t3 
      on t1.tname = t3.tname inner join
      table2 t2
      on t3.title = t2.title
 where (TO_CHAR(date,'yyyy-mm-dd') > '2012-01-01')
 group by tname;
```

This assumes the rest of the query is correct.

Comment: i can't test the query . don't know why. but it's correct here?

Comment: @user3664490 . . . It looks correct to me, although the `nvl()` is redundant.  `count(*)` doesn't return `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

A string comparison of date generally doesn't result in what you really want.
and a group by is needed or a syntax error from oracle should be returned.

```
SELECT tname,NVL(count(*),0) as total 
FROM  table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table3 t3 
   on t1.tname = t3.tname 
inner join table2 t2 
   on t3.title = t2.title
where date > to_date('2012-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
GROUP BY tname;
```